# How do I get all double letter combinations from a string?

Tags: c#

So I have a string with double letters, `commenntt`, how do I get a list of all double/single letter word combinations?
The list should look like

```
{ "commenntt","commennt","commentt","comenntt","commentt","commennt","coment", and whatever else I missed };
```

It may seem like a "let's assess the issue and solve it a different way" scenario, but this function is what I need.

I've tried to figure it out for awhile but can't and the stuff I have tried is too convoluted and unreasonable to show.

Comment: "*the stuff I have tried is too convoluted and unreasonable to show*" - Please add (relevant) attempts and code inside the question - [ask] - How to create a [mre]

Comment: So you have a list of letters and for each position in the list the information if it should be printed one or twice, right? For N letters, these are 2 ^ N possibilities.

Comment: For a word like `comment`, you have `2^7 = 128` possible representations, where 7 is the length of the word. Count up from 0 up to 127, take the bit pattern of those numbers (i.e. from `0000000` to `1111111`), and represent the `0` bits as a single letter, and the `1` bits as double letters. Should be fairly trivial, even in C#.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen - There are only 2^3 possibilities in the OP's question.

Comment: @Enigmativity Quoting from the question: *"The list should look like [...] and whatever else I missed"*. I agree that the question lacks in clarity though, e.g. it is not clear whether `commmment` is a valid option.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen - I read it as the OP wants to take every possible combination of reducing the double letters to single.

Comment: @Enigmativity Possible. Since OP seems to have disengaged already, it might forever remain a mystery. And despite their insistence to the opposite, it feels very much like an XY problem.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wQLuNj